# Update table multiple column values from another table multiple rows by matching IDs

Tags: mysql

I'm Trying to update Table-A (Col1, Col2, Col3) values from Table B (Row1, Row2, Row3) by matching ColID & mapping_id in Row.

Table - A

| ColID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | null | null | null |
| B | null | null | null |
| C | null | null | null |

Table - B

| RowID | Value | mapping_id | Col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1a (this value goes to A-Col1) | A | Col1 |
| 2 | 2a (this value goes to A-Col2) | A | Col2 |
| 3 | 3a (this value goes to A-Col3) | A | Col3 |
| 4 | 1b (this value goes to B-Col1) | B | Col1 |
| 5 | 2b (this value goes to B-Col2) | B | Col2 |
| 6 | 3b (this value goes to B-Col3) | B | Col3 |

**Expected Output**

| ColID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1a | 2a | 3a |
| B | 1b | 2b | 3b |
| C | null | null | null |

My query:

```sql
update Table-A
SET Col1 = (select value
            from Table-B
            where Table-A.ColID = Table-B.mapping.id
            and TableB.Col = 'Col1');
```

When I run this code it's updating Table-A Col1

Like this

| ColID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1a | null | null |
| B | 1b | null | null |
| C | null | null | null |

I'm having more than 30 columns in table, I can't update one by one.

Comment: What are you *really* using, SQL Server or MySQL? I have removed the conflicting tags; please [edit] your question to *retag* the correct (R)DBMS you are using.,

Comment: Have you tried to use `PIVOT` on Table-B?

Answer (score 0):

You can first apply a pivoting operation using:

- [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) operations to extract the corresponding "*Value_*" values for each of the columns
- [`MAX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_max) operations to aggregate rows and select only non-null "*Col1*", "*Col2*", "*Col3*" values

Once you have your "*Table B*" so wrangled (which we're calling ["*cte*"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)), you can carry out the `UPDATE` statement and set "*TableA.Col*" to the corresponding "*cte.Col*" values. You can match values between two tables inside an `UPDATE` statement with a `JOIN` operation.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT mapping_id, 
           MAX(CASE WHEN Col = 'Col1' THEN Value_ END) AS Col1,
           MAX(CASE WHEN Col = 'Col2' THEN Value_ END) AS Col2,
           MAX(CASE WHEN Col = 'Col3' THEN Value_ END) AS Col3
    FROM tabB
    GROUP BY mapping_id
)
UPDATE     tabA
INNER JOIN cte
        ON tabA.ColID = cte.mapping_id
SET tabA.Col1 = cte.Col1,
    tabA.Col2 = cte.Col2,
    tabA.Col3 = cte.Col3;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fhPfKmxFE5TTFyRX5RNHTv/0).